# issue's with gcd and form coding

Tags: php, forms, algorithm, function, math

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Euclidean Algorithm</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method="get" action="EuclidAlgo.php">
            <fieldset>

<label for="remainder">Euclidean Algorithm : </label>
<input type="text" name="NumberA" value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['NumberA'])) ? $_GET['NumberA'] : 5; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="NumberB" value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['NumberB'])) ? $_GET['NumberB'] : 5; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" name='submit' value="submit" />
</fieldset>
</form>

    <?php



    function gcd($a, $b)


    {
        $a = abs($a);
        $b = abs($b);

        if ($a == 0)
        {
            return $b;
        }
        elseif ($b == 0)
        {
            return $a;
        }
        elseif ($a > $b)
        {
            return gcd($b, $a % $b);
        }
        else
        {
            return gcd($a, $b % $a);
        }
    }

    function lcm($a, $b)
    {
        $a = abs($a);
        $b = abs($b);

        if  ($a > $b)
        {
            return ($b / gcd($a, $b)) * $a;
        }
        else
        {
            return ($a / gcd($a, $b)) * $a;
        }
    }

   if (isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    $a = $_GET['NumberA'];
    $b = $_GET['NumberB'];
} else {
     $a = 5;
     $b = 5;    
}
echo gcd($a, $b);
?>
<br />
<?php
echo lcm($a, $b);



    ?>
```

My lcm function is not running correctly for example when i enter 100 and 150 into my program rather than it returning 50 it is returning 200 any ideas, also if i am missing anything important that i need to state just ask rather than complaining or giving my work a low mark.

Comment: why mark my code -1 without telling me why????

Comment: I didn't downvote, but my guess would be because you've told us you're getting errors, but not told us what the errors are. Also, you're not saying what you think the expected result of your code should be. And perhaps because you've sort of scatter-shotted the question with tags without saying whether you think the problem is actually related to your algorithm, your form code or your math.

Comment: i dont know what the errors are i only know what ive said once the submit button is clicked its not running or doing anything and i have said i think the error is within my form code but i just cant see what it is.

Comment: Obvious question, but is the code you have posted in a file called `EuclidAlgo.php`? I am asking as that is what your form is pointing at.

Comment: yeah thats the name of the whole php file

Comment: Based on the comment/code changes you have made, I would really suggest you learn to read and think about error messages. They are telling you EXACTLY what is wrong with your code here. You should read them and then think about how to change your code based on what they are telling you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if (isset($_GET['submit']))
```

instead of

```
if (isset($_GET['gcd']))
```

Why? Because the form doesn't have a field named `gcd`.

---

**EDIT: based on your edit, and some suggestions.**

Change your HTML (suggestion) to look like:

```
<input type="text" name="NumberA" value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['NumberA'])) ? $_GET['NumberA'] : 0; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="NumberB" value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['NumberB'])) ? $_GET['NumberB'] : 0; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" name='submit' value="submit" />
```

This will prevent any 'undefined variable' errors from popping up.

Then end your PHP with:

```
if (isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    $a = $_GET['NumberA'];
    $b = $_GET['NumberB'];
} else {
     $a = 0;
     $b = 0;    
}
echo gcd($a, $b);
```

Comment: thanks changed it but still nothing is happening once submit button is pressed

Comment: Whoa! You changed your code A LOT. Hang on for an update.

Comment: which version of my code did you see before like?

Comment: Updated. It works now, right?

Comment: to make it display the lcm all i have to do is add another echo statement is that correct?

Comment: That's right. `echo lcm($a, $b);`. Note, however, that you will receive an error stating "Warning: Division by zero in ..." the first time you run it. You should change your function `lcm` appropriately.

Comment: yeah I've just realized im receiving errors with it, I've changed my work so that im not getting that specific error message but its not returning the correct number for lcm, im going to update my work if you want to take a lok

Comment: I really think that you should post this as a separate question, and rollback the changes you made for this one.